# Stopping comment spam with links(need suggestion)

Tags: spam, spam-prevention

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I prevent comment spam on sites which I control?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25373/how-can-i-prevent-comment-spam-on-sites-which-i-control)

After bearing 1 year spammy comments with links in those in my 10 sites, finally I've disallowed comment posting with prefix of "http" or "https" ( with message that I'll add prefix http  if needed).

I'm happy with the results.

But could it be hurting site or site visitors in any way? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not have used a regex on http:// or https:// but I woudl rather try a solution such as Askimet. It is believed to be pretty good against spam comments. Or maybe Disqus like comments.

**Can it hurt?**

When trying to give a point of view, I generally confirm what I say, with a couple of links = **yes**. But if the progression of spam ratio has fallen, I could do with restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the best solution is to move to the disqus comment system, that puts this problem in the hands of a much larger business who only earn money when they prevent this kind of thing.

Akismet is another good service that's worth a try.

Other options include automatically `no-follow`-ing the links in your comments - as this makes your site useless to spammers or disallowing `a href` in comments.

For the sake of other future readers, many people sell lists of thousands of websites which haven't applied no-follow to links in their comments section, allowing the spammers to easily and robotically spam your site. Everyone should apply no-follow in their comments it's very easy to do. While no-follow won't stop spammers entirely, it will *stop you being included in the lists for sale*.

Comment: using no-follow won't stop any spammers, especially if you have a larger site where any link brings some visitors as well. You could either moderate comments manually, use an external service as askimet or write a simple filter that discards comments with certain keywords or domains.

Comment: The problem is bots try to post each and every form like commnet/contact us with links in it. It is not related to dofollow/nofollow. Even nofollow does have some value. Pl keep in mind disallowing href in comments is exactly what I'm asking suggestion from you( ie disallowing http in comments).

Comment: @iHaveacomputer it will stop you being included in the lists and doing this has killed spam stone dead on a number of sites I manage. The newer robots check and won't waste their time.

Answer (score 1):

There is another service called [akismet](http://akismet.com/). I recommend you to look at it too.

Comment: I guess you missed the first answer which recommends this solution?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I missed it. Still I write the name correctly and link to it. I think my post has in this case some value too.